# Providing or Filtering assemblies when registering areas for an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, registration, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a large application that currently exists as a hybrid of WebForms and MVC 2.0. Startup of my application is dreadful, and the culprit is primarily because of the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas` call. More specifically, that it is using the `System.Web. Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies` to enumerate all types in assemblies directly referenced by the application and test them to see if they derive from `AreaRegistration`.

Unfortunately, I have a number of third-party assemblies that happen to be quite extensive, so this initial load can be pretty bad. I'd have much better results if I could tell it which assemblies to look for `AreaRegistrations`, or even register areas manually for the time being.

I can gather up all the internals of `AreaRegistration` to create and invoke the registration, but I'm just curious if others have had and worked around this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I put together the following utility to isolate Assemblies for registering Areas. I had to hack out the internals of area registration, but they don't seem terribly complicated and this has been running reasonably well for me:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyCompany.Web.Mvc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides helpful utilities for performing area registration, where <see cref="AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()"/> may not suffice.
    /// </summary>
    public static class AreaRegistrationUtil
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers all areas found in the assembly containing the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">A type that derives from <see cref="AreaRegistration"/> and has a default constructor.</typeparam>
        public static void RegisterAreasForAssemblyOf<T>()
            where T : AreaRegistration, new()
        {
            RegisterAreasForAssemblyOf<T>(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers all areas found in the assembly containing the given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">A type that derives from <see cref="AreaRegistration"/> and has a default constructor.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="state">An object containing state that will be passed to the area registration.</param>
        public static void RegisterAreasForAssemblyOf<T>(object state)
            where T : AreaRegistration, new()
        {
            RegisterAreasForAssemblies(state, typeof (T).Assembly);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers all areas found in the given assemblies.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="assemblies"><see cref="Assembly"/> objects containing the prospective area registrations.</param>
        public static void RegisterAreasForAssemblies(params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            RegisterAreasForAssemblies(null, assemblies);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers all areas found in the given assemblies.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">An object containing state that will be passed to the area registration.</param>
        /// <param name="assemblies"><see cref="Assembly"/> objects containing the prospective area registrations.</param>
        public static void RegisterAreasForAssemblies(object state, params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            foreach (Type type in
                from assembly in assemblies
                from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                where IsAreaRegistrationType(type)
                select type)
            {
                RegisterArea((AreaRegistration) Activator.CreateInstance(type), state);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs area registration using the specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">A type that derives from <see cref="AreaRegistration"/> and has a default constructor.</typeparam>
        public static void RegisterArea<T>()
            where T : AreaRegistration, new()
        {
            RegisterArea<T>(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs area registration using the specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">A type that derives from <see cref="AreaRegistration"/> and has a default constructor.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="state">An object containing state that will be passed to the area registration.</param>
        public static void RegisterArea<T>(object state)
            where T : AreaRegistration, new()
        {
            var registration = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            RegisterArea(registration, state);
        }

        private static void RegisterArea(AreaRegistration registration, object state)
        {
            var context = new AreaRegistrationContext(registration.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes, state);
            string ns = registration.GetType().Namespace;

            if (ns != null) context.Namespaces.Add(string.Format("{0}.*", ns));

            registration.RegisterArea(context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether or not the specified type is assignable to <see cref="AreaRegistration"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">A <see cref="Type"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the specified type is assignable to <see cref="AreaRegistration"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
        private static bool IsAreaRegistrationType(Type type)
        {
            return (typeof (AreaRegistration).IsAssignableFrom(type) && (type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null));
        }
    }
}
```

Easiest way to use this, for me, is

```
AreaRegistrationUtil.RegisterAreasForAssemblyOf<SomeTypeInTargetAssembly>();
```

This has made noticeable improvements in start up time, at the expense of not being able to drop in an area and have the application automatically register it. However, that isn't a concern of mine in this case.

Comment: what is the SomeTypeInTargetAssembly? I tried calling this to my Global.asax but I don't have idea what is it.

Comment: It's some type in the assembly that contains the areas. I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: Love this. Turned my 1104ms init into 14ms.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if this will help in this specific case but could you combine all your 3rd party dlls into one dlls (hence removing the processing of all the individual files). This is what we have done using ILMerge at build time. Works like a charm. It will still need to look at the metadata for the dll (which will now be a bit larger) but it wont have to do as much IO.

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting suggestion for a much larger issue, but there are complications to implementing that. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.