# Improving ASP.NET MVC startup performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to improve the speed at which my MVC2 app is starting up.

I did a first round of performance sampling, and it appears that the

```
MvcAreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas
```

is taking up most of the startup time.

I read [here](http://mikevdm.com/BlogEntry/Key/MVC-and-Application-Start-Time--Multiple-Projects-Areas) that you can manually register the area's as well, and I would like to try that out, but I'm not sure how the syntax works on that page.

So my (first) question woud be: how can I register my Area's manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [this super handy area registration utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496956/providing-or-filtering-assemblies-when-registering-areas-for-an-asp-net-mvc-2-0-a/2715148#2715148).  Not only does it make registration easier, but also way faster since it doesn't scan every loaded assembly for areas.

Answer (score 5):

First prepare yourself a helper method in Global.asax like this:

```
private static void RegisterArea<T>(RouteCollection routes, object state) where T : AreaRegistration 
{ 
  AreaRegistration registration = (AreaRegistration)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)); 
  AreaRegistrationContext registrationContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(registration.AreaName, routes, state); 
  string areaNamespace = registration.GetType().Namespace; 
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(areaNamespace)) 
    registrationContext.Namespaces.Add(areaNamespace + ".*"); 
  registration.RegisterArea(registrationContext); 
}
```

Now you can use this helper method for manual registration in Application_Start like this:

```
//Replace AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); with lines like those
RegisterArea<FirstAreaRegistration>(RouteTable.Routes, null); 
RegisterArea<SecondAreaRegistration>(RouteTable.Routes, null);
```

The AreaRegistration classes are created by Visual Studio when you add new Area, you can find them in Areas/AreaName directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely by hand and avoid using RegisterArea implementations.

Check this article:
http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/07/mvc-areas-routes-order-of-routes-matter/

In short - you need to add "area" DataToken to your route:

```
private void RegisterAreas(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    var route = routes.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_Default",
        "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "MyProject.Areas.*" }
    ).DataTokens.Add("Area", "CDR");
}
```